# Newest date in dictionary using Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, dictionary

Having an array of dictionaries I'd like to obtain the most updated record. For instance, consider the following record:

```
var myArray = [{
  itemA: {
  name: "Joe Blow",
  date: "Mon Jan 31 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)"
  }, 
  itemB: {
  name: "Sam Snead",
  date: "Sun March 30 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)"
  }, 
  itemC: {
  name: "John Smith",
  date: "Sat Apr 29 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)"
  }}];
```

which then I would need to get the most updated record first:

```
myArray.sort((d1, d2) => new Date(d2.date).getTime() - new Date(d1.date).getTime());
```

However, I am not getting the correct result. Would you know how to get it working?

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "most updated record"? Using your example data, what would be the most updated record? Would you expect the correct result to be ItemC, for example, since it contains the most recent date of the three entries? Also, do you mean to have your list of objects inside another object (resulting in an array with length of 1), or just an array of length 3 that has a list of objects?

Comment: the most updated record is itemC.

Comment: The spec defines one supported [date time string format](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format), and those date strings are not in that format. While a JS engine implementation might parse those strings, it's not guaranteed.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Once the items are sorted, you can grab the item sorted first or last to get the oldest or newest item. As noted in my answer, keep in mind that your current approach attempts to sort an array of length 1. So, it may be worth checking to clearly understand if the current schema reflects the way you want your data organized. But given you are sorting an object, check my answer for an example of a working solution/approach. Hopefully that helps clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I have refactored your code a little bit.

first of all, your myArray contains only one object. you cannot sort an object like that. therefore I change the structure of your array.

here is a working example:

```js
var myArray = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Sam Snead",
    date: "Sun March 30 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)"
  }, 
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Joe Blow",
    date: "Mon Jan 31 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)"
  }, 
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "John Smith",
    date: "Sat Apr 29 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)"
  }
];


myArray.sort((d1, d2) => new Date(d2.date).getTime() - new Date(d1.date).getTime());

console.log(myArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the record with the latest date, you can iterate through the collection and store a record if it satisfies the comparator.

```js
const
  identityFn = (x) => x,
  findBy = (collection, accessor, comparator) => {
    let result, prev, record, i;
    if (collection && collection.length) {
      for (i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
        record = collection[i];
        if (!prev || comparator(accessor(record), prev)) {
          result = record;
          prev = accessor(record);
        }
      };
    }
    return result;
  },
  findMax = (collection, accessor = identityFn) =>
    findBy(collection, accessor, (curr, prev) => curr > prev);

const
  myArray = [{
    itemA: { name: "Joe Blow"   , date: "Mon Jan 31 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)" },
    itemB: { name: "Sam Snead"  , date: "Sun Mar 30 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)" },
    itemC: { name: "John Smith" , date: "Sat Apr 29 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)" },
    itemD: { name: "Jane Doe"   , date: null                                      },
    itemE: null,
  }],
  extractDate = (data) => data ? new Date(data?.date) : null,
  [key, record] = findMax(
    Object.entries(myArray[0]),       // Access the entries (key/val pairs)
    ([key, val]) => extractDate(val)  // Map the parsed date
  );

console.log(record); // Data for key "itemC"
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

If you want to sort the records, you can modify the code above like so:

```js
const sortBy = (collection, accessor, comparator) =>
  collection.sort((a, b) => comparator(accessor(a), accessor(b)));

const
  myArray = [{
    itemA: { name: "Joe Blow"   , date: "Mon Jan 31 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)" },
    itemB: { name: "Sam Snead"  , date: "Sun Mar 30 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)" },
    itemC: { name: "John Smith" , date: "Sat Apr 29 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)" },
    itemD: { name: "Jane Doe"   , date: null                                      },
    itemE: null,
  }],
  extractDate = (data) => data ? new Date(data?.date) : null,
  sorted = sortBy(
    Object.entries(myArray[0]),       // Access the entries (key/val pairs)
    ([key, val]) => extractDate(val), // Map the parsed date
    (curr, prev) => prev - curr       // Same as (DESC): (curr - prev) * -1
  );

console.log(sorted);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

---

### Edit

- Added `null` values
- Changed `([key, { date }]) => new Date(date)` to `([key, val]) => extractDate(val)` to handle `null` values

Comment: Thanks @Mr. Polywhirl, it is an excellent implementation. One question, how would you add a safeguard to avoid nulls in date field and avoid getting Cannot read properties of null (reading 'date')? Would be enough to go with this? ([key, value]) => value? new Date(value.update_timestamp):null,

Comment: @JohnBarton I added `null` values and guards.

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach attempts to sort an array of length 1, and the item in the array is an object that represents each record as a property (another object). This makes it a bit inefficient to iterate over your data. Do you need the `ItemA` labeling for each record and, if so, why not make this part of the object describing the record itself along with `date` and `name`?

You can look at `Object.entries()`, `Object.keys()`, or `Object.values()` for ways to make use of object data in an array in order to sort or map over your data.

Assuming your current schema and assuming you had an array with many such objects, if you wanted to find the most recent record in the list for some item `i` in your array, here is a solution.

You can create a sorted array of objects representing each record for the array item in question. Once sorted, you can take the first or last record to get the oldest or newest. See example below.

```
const myArray = [
  {
    itemA: {
      name: "Joe Blow",
      date: "Mon Jan 31 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)"
    },
    itemC: {
      name: "John Smith",
      date: "Sat Apr 29 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)"
    },
    itemB: {
      name: "Sam Snead",
      date: "Sun March 30 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)"
    }
  }
];

const sortedEntries = myArray.map((entry) => {
  const records = Object.values(entry);
  const sortedRecords = records.sort(function (prev, next) {
    return new Date(prev.date) < new Date(next.date) ? -1 : 1;
  });
  return sortedRecords;
});

// the array with records for each entry now sorted as an array from oldest to most recent date
console.log("sorted entries: ", sortedEntries);

// for example purposes, accessing your array by index, assuming you had more than 1 item in the array
const i = 0;

// get the record with most recent date for this array item
console.log(
  "most recent record for example entry is: ",
  sortedEntries[i][sortedEntries[i].length - 1]
);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-shadow-s36cf3

Answer (score 0):

This snippet should help you:

```js
const myArray = [
  {
    itemA: {
      name: "Joe Blow",
      date: "Mon Jan 31 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)"
    },
    itemC: {
      name: "John Smith",
      date: "Sat Apr 29 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)"
    },
    itemB: {
      name: "Sam Snead",
      date: "Sun March 30 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)"
    }
  }
];

const sortedArray = myArray.map(entry => {
  let tmpObj = {};
  let tmpSorted =  Object.keys(entry).sort((prev, next) => {
    return Date.parse(entry[next]?.date) - Date.parse(entry[prev]?.date);
  });

  tmpSorted.forEach(e => {
    tmpObj[e] = entry[e];
  })

  return tmpObj;
});


console.log(sortedArray);
```